# Test whether T-SQL FLOAT column values are in accetable YYY.QQ format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find any values that are not in the expected list for a column. In this case, I'm talking about valid `year.quarter` values.  So:

```
Quarter  | Is_Okay
-------------------
   0     | no
   2015.1| yes
   NULL  | No
   2014.4| Yes
   2016  | No
  NULL   | No
```

Comment: And what would you want a query to return?

Comment: Just return true if valid, I suppose.

Comment: What a horrible way to store the dates! What's wrong with `datetime` storing the 1st day of the quarter? At least it is comparable with the dates falling into and outside the quarter.

Comment: Why in the world would you use a float here? It is about 3 levels away from the proper datatype for dates. We have the date datatype which would be the proper datatype. But even if you insist on forcing this into a numeric datatype (which is folly imho) you should at least an exact numeric datatype instead of an approximate one like float.

Comment: Is this issue solved? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

Float is really bad choice for encoding yyyy.q I should say.

You may hard-code it as a computed column

```
create table t(
    quarter float,
    is_ok as 
       case when quarter > 9999.4 or quarter < 1000.1 then 'No' 
         when round(quarter*10,0) != quarter*10 then 'No' 
         when cast(round(quarter*10,0) as int)%10 between 1 and 4 then 'Yes'
         else 'No' 
       end 
    );

insert t(quarter)
values (2015.1), (2015.099),(2015.4),(null)
--  max value, will our expression raise overflow ?
, (1.7976931348623158E+308)
;
select * from t;
```

Alternatively create a view

```
create table t_base(
    quarter float
    );
go

create view t as
    select quarter,  
    case when quarter > 9999.4 or quarter < 1000.1 then 'No' 
         when round(quarter*10,0) != quarter*10 then 'No' 
         when cast(round(quarter*10,0) as int)%10 between 1 and 4 then 'Yes'
         else 'No' 
    end is_ok
from t_base;
go

insert t(quarter)
values (2015.1), (2015.099),(2015.4),(null)
, (1.7976931348623158E+308)
;

select * from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

One very straight string-based approach was this:

- multiply by ten
- cast to `INT`
- check the total length which must be 5
- check the last digit, which must be `in(1,2,3,4)`

**attention** This would return *valid* if the value was 2016.345, but I think - seeing your values - this is not the problem...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Quarter] FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (0),(2015.1),(NULL),(2014.4),(2016),(2014.5),(102.435);

WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT [Quarter]
           ,ISNULL(CAST([Quarter]*10 AS INT),0) AS byTen
     FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN LEN(byTen) /*implicit conversion*/ <> 5 THEN 'No'
            ELSE CASE WHEN RIGHT(byTen,1) IN('1','2','3','4') THEN 'Yes'
                 ELSE 'No' END
       END AS Is_Okay
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I could think of doing this is apply some string rules:

1. Length Must be 6
2. Character 5 must be a '.' (decimal)
3. Last character must be between 1-4
4. *Optional: Add year range to first 4 characters - I didn't bother.

This illustrates each "rejection" -- just change the verbiage of each ELSE statement to "No" or "Fail" as you see fit.

```
DECLARE @WhatNotToDoInSQL TABLE ([Quarter] FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @WhatNotToDoInSQL ([Quarter])
VALUES (0),
       (2015.1),
       (NULL),
       (2014.4),
       (214.4),
       (2016),
       (2016.12),
       (2016.5)

SELECT *, 
       --LEN([Quarter]) as [length6],
       --CHARINDEX('.',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),[Quarter])) as [decimalLocation],
       --RIGHT([Quarter],1) as [right1],
       CASE WHEN LEN([Quarter])=6 THEN -- length must be 6
          CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),[Quarter]))=5 THEN -- must have a . at position 5
             CASE WHEN CONVERT(INT,RIGHT([Quarter],1)) BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN 'Yes' -- right most integer must be between 1 and 4
             ELSE 'No 1-4 in Position 6' 
             END
          ELSE 'No Decimal At Position 5'
          END
       ELSE 'No Length'     
       END
FROM @WhatNotToDoInSQL
```